# Split the equation based on first dot (.)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest for how to split the equation into two parts based on first dot. Earlier I got the [suggestion to Split the Equation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047187/3049413) based on BREAK comment text from michael.hor257k, now it is required to split on period.

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <body><sec><title>The sec 1</title><p>Text 1</p></sec></body>
    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <mi>A</mi>
            <mn>4.651</mn>
            <mi>The next text</mi>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>
    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <mrow>
                <mrow><mi>B</mi></mrow>
                <mrow><mn>4.651</mn></mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mi>The next text</mi>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="root" select="//inline-formula/*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//inline-formula">
                <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(., '.')">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$root">
                            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each >
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:param name="i" tunnel="yes"/>
            <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::text()[contains(., '.')]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<root>
    <body><sec><title>The sec 1</title><p>Text 1</p></sec></body>
    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <mi>A</mi>
            <mn>4.</mn>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>
    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <!--Text node, before dot is removed -->
            <mn>651</mn>
            <mi>The next text</mi>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>

    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <mrow>
                <mrow><mi>B</mi></mrow>
                <mrow><mn>4.</mn></mrow>
            </mrow>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>
    <inline-formula>
        <math display="inline">
            <mrow>
                <!--Text node, before dot is removed -->
                <mrow><mn>651</mn></mrow>
            </mrow>
            <mi>The next text</mi>
        </math>
    </inline-formula>
</root>
```

Comment: You've spent some time now on SO, and in the xslt corner. Please learn to use the _tag system_ correctly. Questions about XSLT 2.0 should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the answer to the previous question, provided by michael.hor257k, there are a couple of key differences to the XSLT you are using in this question. In the previous answer, which splits on comments, it iterates the number of times such comments appear

```
<xsl:for-each select="0 to count(//comment()[.='Break'])">
```

So, in the new solution, you need to iterate over the number of times a text node occurs with a dot in:

```
<xsl:for-each select="0 to count(//text()[contains(., '.')])">
```

Then, in the "identity" template, the previous answer checks the number of comments below the current node to see if it showed be copied:

```
<xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::text()[count(preceding::comment()[.='Break'])=$i]">
```

This means, in the new solution, you might start off by writing this:

```
<xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::text()[count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')])=$i]">
```

However, this would not be entirely correct, as the node with the dot in would be copied to the first part of the split, but the second part of the split would not contain the node at all.

The actually expression needed is this:

```
<xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::text()[(count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')])=($i - 1) and contains(., '.')) or count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')])=$i]">
```

This would copied the node containing the dot to both parts of the split. You would then need a whole new template to actually split the text.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/*" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::inline-formula)]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="0 to count(//text()[contains(., '.')])">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$root/inline-formula">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each >
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:param name="i" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::text()[(count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')])=($i - 1) and contains(., '.')) or count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')])=$i]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '.')]">
    <xsl:param name="i" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(preceding::text()[contains(., '.')]) = $i">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')" /><xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '.')" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions and nice explanation about code, working perfectly, +1

Comment: One small clarification, please, equations should break only on first dot, rest of the text or part of equation should not break even if equation having second dot in following text.

Comment: In between inline-formula, if any test presents, then the text (non equation) is moving above the all equations.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, I am afraid. The input XML in your question has two text nodes with dots in them, and your expected output shows them both being split. My answer does this and the output should match your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also wondering why you need such a transformation, but here is a possible solution. The rules are not clear to me, e.g.

- Can there be more than 2 `mn` elements in an `inline-formula`?
- Is it always the string value of `mn` that needs to be split into separate elements?
- You are saying the split should occur on the *first* `.`in the value of `mn`, but multiple dots do not make sense in a single `mn` element in MathML

But setting aside all this, perhaps it's easier to tackle the problem with two separate transformations. The first simply separates the content of `mn` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="mn[contains(.,'.')]">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\.')">
            <mn>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </mn>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The intermediate result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <body>
      <sec>
         <title>The sec 1</title>
         <p>Text 1</p>
      </sec>
   </body>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline">
         <mi>A</mi>
         <mn>4.</mn>
         <mn>651</mn>
         <mi>The next text</mi>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline">
         <mrow>
            <mrow>
               <mi>B</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
               <mn>4.</mn>
               <mn>651</mn>
            </mrow>
         </mrow>
         <mi>The next text</mi>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
</root>
```

Then, apply a second transformation similar to the following. By the way, it seems to be a good opportunity to use the special mode keywords `#all` and `#current`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="inline-formula[count(//mn) gt 1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="first"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="second"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mn[position() = 2] | mi[. = 'The next text']" mode="first"/>
    <xsl:template match="mi[. != 'The next text']" mode="second"/>

    <xsl:template match="mn[position() = 1]" mode="second">
        <xsl:comment>Text node, before dot is removed</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the final result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <body>
      <sec>
         <title>The sec 1</title>
         <p>Text 1</p>
      </sec>
   </body>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline">
         <mi>A</mi>
         <mn>4.</mn>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline"><!--Text node, before dot is removed-->
         <mn>651</mn>
         <mi>The next text</mi>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline">
         <mrow>
            <mrow>
               <mi>B</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
               <mn>4.</mn>
            </mrow>
         </mrow>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
   <inline-formula>
      <math display="inline">
         <mrow>
            <mrow/>
            <mrow><!--Text node, before dot is removed-->
               <mn>651</mn>
            </mrow>
         </mrow>
         <mi>The next text</mi>
      </math>
   </inline-formula>
</root>
```

The result contains an empty `mrow` element. If it matters, you could add another template along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="mrow/mrow[not(mn)]" mode="second"/>
```

to the second transformation, but, again, it is not clear how empty elements should be dealt with.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, this is one of the live requirement from Rendering team, here we need to do equation split based on **FIRST dot**, of course that is **MN** element and '**The next text**' is may be any content or any number of elements which can be followed by the first MN (having dot).