# Adding HTML tags with XSLT on the fly

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML document containing this:

```
<d1/>
<p1>...</p1>
<p2>...</p2>
<d2/>
<p3>...</p3>
<d3/>
```

Where pn are elements with possibly subelements and other stuff, and dn indicates where an HTML DIV tag wrapping the p tags should begin, but without a corresponding closing tag, this is only indicated implicitly by the next dn tag. The desired HTML output is this:

```
<div>
<p1>...</p1>
<p2>...</p2>
</div>
<div>
<p3>...</p3>
</div>
```

I have written an XSLT to introduce the `<div>` and `</div>` tags on the fly, using the following:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;</xsl:text>
```

and

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
```

and this works on Safari, but it fails on FireFox, which makes me suspect that it's not the right way to do it.
Do you have a better idea that will work on every browser?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are the tags really numbered the way you show? And if yes, do you really want to retain the numbering of the  `p` tags in your output?

Comment: No, that's just an example. It's a mix of different tags.

Comment: So how exactly can the "divider" tag be identified?

Comment: The divider tags are like that, I was talking about the p tags.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. The concern here is whether `*[starts-with(name(), 'd')]` (which both Martin Honnen and I have used) selects **only** the divider tags. -- It's also not clear how exactly you want to process the other nodes; both answers (now) assume that you want to copy them *as is*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. After reading your message I realized that I could change the name of the d tags to make them unique, so the selection was easier. However, I've been trying to implement your suggestion and I think it's not gonna work, because I found that the d tags occur in some cases in the middle of the text of other tags: <p>this is some <d/> text </p>. I don't see how to work it out.

Comment: That's going to be **much** more complicated. Could you at least introduce some constraints as to what you might have? Doing this generically is even harder: keep in mind that a split like that requires closing of all open tags for the first part, and reconstructing the entire hierarchy for the second part of the text. In theory at least, you could also have  `<p>this is some <d/>text <d/>that ends here</p>`. --- IIUC, you are doing this in a browser - i.e. for display only. Perhaps you should re-assess your options.

Comment: That's right, it's only for display, and indeed it's much harder. I was considering doing it with JS perhaps (but I might have the problem you mention of having to reconstruct the whole hierarchy). Since the DIV tags are in fact text boxes, is there a way to create a text box and to redirect HTML output to a different text box when a d tag is found?  Thank you again tons! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know enough JS to answer that. In XSLT, I would probably do a preliminary pass to handle all nodes that contain both a divider and text node/s. But the problem of unknown hierarchy still remains. In the initial statement of the problem, all the `d` markers were direct children of the root. If they can be anywhere, then you will have to do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045391/split-xml-nodes-based-on-particular-text/27047187#27047187

Answer (score 2):

You could use a technique known as "*sibling recursion*".

Given a well-formed input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <d1/>
    <p1>a</p1>
    <p2>b</p2>
    <d2/>
    <p3>c</p3>
    <d3/>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), 'd')][position()!=last()]"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'd')]">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(starts-with(name(), 'd'))]"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'd'))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(starts-with(name(), 'd'))]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>b</p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>c</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support disable-output-escaping because it does not serialize the result tree. The problem is a grouping problem, one way to solve it is to use a key:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group" match="body/*[not(starts-with(local-name(), 'd'))]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'd')][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'd')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'd')]">
    <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', generate-id())"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That would create an empty `div` however at the end of your sample, so you might want to change the last template to

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'd')]">
    <xsl:if test="key('group', generate-id())">
      <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', generate-id())"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```