# Process page number in middle of paragraph with XSLT

Tags: python, xslt, lxml

I have XML with a page break in the middle of a paragraph.  It looks like this:

```
<P format="center">
  text before page break
  <?PageStart number='5'?>
  <BoundaryDataReference idref="bd-005"/>
  text after page break
</P>
```

Th page break is indicated by both the processing directive and the BoundaryDataReference tag.

I'd like to present this as HTML and show the page break in the proper place.  Something like this:

```
<p class="text-center">text before page break</p>
<p>-5-</p>
<p class="text-center">text after page break</p>
```

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this with Python.  Preferably with the the Python LXML library (XSLT 1.0), but I'd consider other Python options.

One tricky option is that the P element may have attributes that should be included both before and after the page break (shown as `class="text-center"` above).

In response to the comment, it looks like the processing instruction and the BoundaryDataReference tag are always a direct child of the P element and are not further nested.

Comment: That'd be using XSLT version 1.0?

Comment: Would your processing instruction appear as a child of any element other than `<P>`? Might it be nested within another element that was a child of a `<P>`?

Comment: @newname I have posted an answer based on your assumption, but I must say it seems very unlikely that a page break cannot occur in the middle of italic text, for example. In such case the problem becomes much more difficult (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/27045391/3016153). A better approach, IMHO, would be to insert a `span` in the middle of the text wherever a page break is found and style it appropriately.

Comment: Also note that with SaxonC https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml from Saxonica, available in the open-source HE edition, there is an option to run XSLT 3 from Python https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation11/index.html#!starting

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I found an example where bold text crossed the page break and the XML ended the bold text before the break and restarted it after the break.  It looks like the XML creator is doing the right thing for inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT you could probably use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="P[BoundaryDataReference]">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | BoundaryDataReference/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select='substring-before(substring-after(processing-instruction("PageStart"), "&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | BoundaryDataReference/following-sibling::node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

But of course you will need other templates too.

Note that this assumes a paragraph can contain at most one page break.